# Need to add a pop-up on a particular arrtibute, which says a small line about it

Tags: magento2

**Please check the screenshot below**, there is a mouse hover pop-up showing on one of my attribute & this is my old website.

> I want to intergate something like this in my new website which is in
>   Magento 2.

[image: Old Website M1]

[image: New Website M2]

Comment: Add tool-tip and style it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this module for product attribute tooltip.

**[Magento 2 attribute tooltip module](https://github.com/Spaggel/Tooltip)**

Comment: Do I have to intall it like a regular plugin, by copying all the files in a folder ?

Comment: Yes. you can install it both ways. you can download and then copy-paste the Module folder to Magento app/code. You may also user composer add Run composer require spaggel/too to install the module.

Comment: cool thanks will try it today.

Comment: its doesnt work on magento 2.3 :(